# Creating a stopwatch timer in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, sdk

I have created the layout and here is its code but I don't know how should I change the mainactivity.java and also what are the things which I should add to string.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/androidtimer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Android Timer"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:gravity="bottom|center" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text=" start "
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="startTimer"
/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text=" stop "
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="stopTimer"

    />
           </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

It'll be great if you can give me some pointers for continuing. I am new to Android mobile development and couldn't find a step by step tutorial for a stopwatch timer.

Comment: Add all your text values to strings.xml and then reference them. Your text sizes could go in your dimens.xml. Not sure what you mean by changing the main activity.

Comment: @BobbyDigital thanks. say where do you add public void `stopTimer(View view) {
 timerTask.cancel();
 timerTask=null;
 n=0;`
} don't you add it to MainActivity.java? Where should I add the onClick methods for each of the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is simply write code like as bellow.

```
boolean isCounterON = true;
while(isCounterON){
 if(isStart){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   //update your view to 1 Second 
    }
}

 onStartButtonClick(){
 isStart=true;
 }

 onStopButtonClick(){
 isStart=false;
 }
```

Thats it

Comment: Should this code be written in MainActivity.java? Also how to link the onStartButtonClick with the name of the start button? Like in Visual Studio you double click on a button and you are guided to its method and you can write your code there but I am kind of confused where I can write my methods in Android SDK.

Comment: if your xml name is string.xml then go to string.java & implement actionListener on it. just STUDY ACTIONLISTENER code & add it to your file your file. its only 2 line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom timer using `Timer` and `TimerTasks` in **Java**. I have added comments into this code, so its self explanatory, i hope this will be helpful to you. This code contains the **working logic**, you can use it with any view you want to.

#### Code

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class StopWatch {
    private long time_counter = 45;  // Seconds to set the Countdown from
    private Timer timer;           

    public void startCountDown(){
        timer = new Timer();        // A thread of execution is instantiated
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println((--time_counter));

                if(time_counter == 0){
                    timer.cancel(); // timer is cancelled when time reaches 0
                }
            }
        },0,1000); 
                    // 0 is the time in second from when this code is to be executed
                    // 1000 is time in millisecond after which it has to repeat
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        StopWatch s = new StopWatch();
        s.startCountDown();
    }
}
```